# How to delay call function without setTimeout ? Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to delay call of function for few seconds.
I have solution which work but enough good.

```
  public recieveNewContact() {
      this.allData();
      setTimeout(() => {  
         this.lastAddedItem()
      }, 100)
  }


  public ngOnInit() { 
    this.allData()
  }

  allData() {
      this.accountsService.getContactPerson().subscribe(
         (data) => {
             console.log(data)
        }
      )
    }
```

This is work good but i don't like this...
I need better solution maybe with rxjs ? Delay ?

**which is very important.**

In this case, I don't need this:

```
  allData() {
      this.accountsService.getContactPerson().subscribe(
         (data) => {
             console.log(data)
             this.lastAddedItem()
        }
      )
    }
```

Because i wan't to load lastAddedItem() on init.... Only when is recieveNewContact triggered.

I will try to explain once again:

```
  public recieveNewContact() {
      this.allData(); 
      this.lastAddedItem()// here to be called when is allData finished without setTimeout
  }
```

Comment: Why dont you like it? explain the reasons behind needing a different option

Comment: Here is a simple example. I delayed calling the function for 3 seconds but my http call takes ( need ) 5 seconds to load for example. And then the whole system breaks down because of that.

Comment: why don't you just set a flag on `receiveNewContact`? something like `callLastAdded` which you set to `false` on your `ngOnInit` function and to `true` on your `recieveNewContact` function.
So you would just need to check the flag in your `subscribe` callback

Comment: Can you explain the flow here? on `ngOnInit` you are calling `allData()` and getting all contact persons. So when exactly are you calling `recieveNewContact()` and what is `lastAddedItem()`  function? Is it an API call?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use either `delay` (if you are 100% sure of the completation time) or `finalize` (if you want to be sure it will wait no matter how long it takes) (rxjs).

Is it necessary to call allData function everytime since you can keep local copy of data in variable and then do the adjustment on it? Or is lastAddedItem API call?

Also I would suggest to set allData as private since don't want it to be called from teplate or another component.